# Does LIBGDX Box2d still work?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I wanted to try out Box2d and wrote similar code to one that is in tutorial, everything renders properly, but nothing updates and there are no exceptions. Please help me i think i am going insane.

```
@Override
public void create () {
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10f), true);
    r = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(100, 100);
    camera.translate(50, 50, 0);
    BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
    bd.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bd.position.set(50, 50);
    Body body = world.createBody(bd);
    CircleShape cs = new CircleShape();
    cs.setRadius(1);
    FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
    fd.shape = cs;
    body.createFixture(fd);
    cs.dispose();
    BodyDef b = new BodyDef();
    b.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
    b.position.set(30, 30);
    Body bo = world.createBody(b);
    PolygonShape ps = new PolygonShape();
    ps.setAsBox(10, 3);
    FixtureDef f = new FixtureDef();
    f.shape = ps;
    bo.createFixture(f);
    ps.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    r.render(world, camera.combined);
    camera.update();
    world.step(1/60, 6, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

of course box2D still work with Libgdx

your problem is this line

```
 world.step(1/60, 6, 2);
```

try do this

```
 world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);
```

your time step was considerer 0 cause 1/60 interger is 0

I have testedd your code it will work !

Good luck